# Frobenius' Theorem on normal p-complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying Frobenius' Theorem on normal p-complement. And I met some problem when following the outline of the proof.

> Theorem: Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $P \in Sylp(G)$. If for all subgroups $U$ of $P$, $N_G(U)$ is p-nilpotent (i.e.has a normal p-complement), so is $G$.

WLOG, suppose $P$ is not trivial and $O_p(G)=1$. Let $Q=Z(P)$ be the center of $P$. Then $Q \neq1$ and $Q \lhd N_G(P)$. One may use contradiction assumption to prove $Q$ is weakly closed in $P$ with respect to $G$. Then by Hall-Wielandt's theorem, $P \ \cap G'=P \ \cap N_G(Q)'$ and therefore, $G /G'(p) \cong P/P \ \cap G'\cong P/P \ \cap N_G(Q)' \cong N_G(Q)/N_G(Q)'(p)$ where $G'(p)$ denotes the inverse image in $G$ of $O_{p'}(G/G')$. Then what should I do next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So $G/G'(p)$ is a proper quotient of $G$ of order a power of $p$. Now, by induction on $|G|$ you can assume that $G'(p)$ has a normal $p$-complement, and hence so does $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, but I can't see why $N_G(Q)/N_G(Q)'(p)$ is of order a power of $p$. Suppose it's trivial and since $N_G(Q)=PO_{p'}(N_G(Q))$, then $N_G(Q)'(p)=P'O_{p'}(N_G(Q)$. Hence, $P=P'$, giving $P$ is abelian. But where is the contradiction?

Comment: $p$-groups are nilpotent, so a nontrivial $p$-group cannot satisfy $P=P'$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I made a huge mistake: $P=P'$ doesn't give $P$ is abelian. Thanks a lot!